# How do you calculate the average wagering of a casino offer?

Tags: statistics, expected-value

I'm trying to calculate the expected value of casino offers that involve wagering. Let's say I have a £50 bonus that has to be wagered 40x (£2000 total) on a slot with an RTP of 97%. It says online that I need to calculate this using...

```
Estimated value = Bonus – (Average Wagering * House Edge)
```

This makes sense because when you lose your bonus you don't need to keep wagering. So my question is how do you calculate the average wagering?

Comment: A link to that online website would help.

Comment: Here's the site https://mikecruickshank.com/casino-bonus-ev-calculator/

Comment: Now your question makes sense! But the answer is: there is no best average wager. It depends on your aims. As the site explains, you have to choose between going for a large win or minimising the chance of going bust. You just have to run the site's simulations for various average wagers to find out what's best for you.

Comment: I see, so it's a simulation and not a calculator. How does it simulate this though, if I play 1 spins on the simulator, what calculations are they doing to return a random result that takes into account both the RTP and the variance of the game?